# LARAVEL: What laravel x is version 1.3.3?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I'm beginner in Laravel framework. I want to know if I'm using Laravel 5? or the number of Laravel I'm using. Thank you!

EDIT: I'm using windows platform

Comment: Check your composer.json file

Comment: You could always just download Laravel from the repo and then you'll know for certain ;) https://github.com/laravel/laravel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two ways:

In your laravel home directory, type:

```
php artisan --version
```

Or you can check in this file:

```
vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Application.php
```

where you will see something like:

```
const VERSION = 'x.x.xx';
```

Taken from [here](http://www.elcoderino.com/check-laravel-version).

Comment: It says version 5.2.31 , so I'm using laravel 5.2?

Answer (score 0):

You can see the version of your Laravel installation in composer.json. Take a look at it and search for this line:

```
"laravel/framework": "5.2.*",
```

You can also do

```
php artisan --version
```

from your terminal / dos prompt

Take a look at the Laravel release notes for more information about the Laravel versions: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/releases

Answer (score 0):

With command Prompt

php artisan --version

or
Go to composer.json

you will find "laravel/framework": "5.5.*", something like this